# Opening the same domain (website) under different IP address

Tags: networking, dns, webserver, cdn

With CDN (content Delivery Network) and similar services the same domain (website) can be accessible at different IP addresses.

I can force the browser to contact the host that I prefer (the VPS one, the CDN one) by simply editing the `hosts` file.

But I would like to check both of the version with a monitoring tool. Is it possible to force different IP resolution of an host for every call I make to that host?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you just hit the IPs directly and modify the host header of your HTTP request?

Comment: @prateek61: how can I do that? if I connect to http://<my-website-ip>/ it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to individually monitor instances of websites on different servers, then one approach would be to install an DNS server in your network, and resolve the host to the IP addresses yourself.

You would want to set a low TTL on each A record to make sure that each resolution resulted in a different IP address.

For example:

```
www.domain.com. 10 A 111.111.111.111
www.domain.com. 10 A 111.111.111.112
```

This assumes that you have a single website served by the two IP addresses on the end.

The `10` value is the TTL and tells the client how long the record is valid for before it should query the server again.  As there are two possible IP addresses, the DNS server will "round-robin" and serve them one at a time.  So if your polling was every 10 seconds, this would alternate between the two IP addresses.

Comment: Can I do it in the host file of window? Would it work in round robin?